# Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated in include()

Tags: php, include, pass-by-reference, deprecated

I moved my website from one server to another. Everything runs, but since I have the new server, the logs

> Deprecated function: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated in include() (line 6 of /ascript.php).

In the script it says the following on line 6:

> include("some_file.inc");

So what is wrong here? There is no pass by reference, as far as I can see? Is it because of the double quotes?
Some additional info, I moved from a server with php 5.3.22 to a server with php 5.3.24

Best regards,

Geert

Comment: does your some_file.inc contain a function call with an argument that starts with &?

Comment: look at within `some_file.inc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some_file.inc there has to be some function call where a reference is passed into a function. To do that the function has to be declared as `function example(&$modificable) {...}` instead of `function example($modificable) {...}` and be called with `example(&$modificable)`

This deprecation notice has been there for a long time. The most probable reason it's popping up now is that your new server has a different error reporting configuration, check the php.ini for differences.

In any case, since PHP 5.4 that code will result in a fatal error instead of a deprecation notice, so the right solution is to fix the problem in some_file.inc.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was quickly solved by seacrhing for '&$' in some_file.inc .